# how to manipulate, on document.ready, elements which were created on document.ready

Tags: jquery

Here's the scenario: I have a menubar.js script, which, when the page loads, queries the server for user's permissions, and then creates a menubar based on them. code snippet:

```
$(function () {
    //initialize the header buttons according to user's permissions
    InitializeCurrentUser();
});

function InitializeCurrentUser() {
    //get current user
    $.ajax(
            {
                url: "../Login/LoginService.asmx/GetCurrentUser",
                success: function (result) {
                    var currentUserRoles = result.d;
                    output = '<ul class="Header">   ';
                    if ($.inArray("reports", currentUserRoles) > -1) {
                    output += '<a href="../Reports/Reports.aspx" ><li id="lnkReports">Reports </li></a>';
                    }
                    //etc...
                    console.log('generating menu');
                    $("#HeaderMenu").html(output);
                }
            });
}
```

This script is included in all my pages.
Now, i'd like to mark the `<li>` representing the current page with a 'current' class.
I've added `var currentPage` to my menubar.js script, and on each page (for example, in reportsPage.js):

```
$(function() {

    //set this page as the current page; 
    currentPage = Enum.Page.Reports;
});
```

and in menubar.js: a function which is called on document.ready:

```
function SetCurrentPage() {
    $("#HeaderMenu li").removeClass('current');
    var liElement = null;
    switch (currentPage) {

        case Enum.Page.Reports:
            liElement = $("#lnkReports");
            break;
    }

    console.log('adding a class to: ');
    console.log(liElement);
    liElement.addClass('current');
}
```

the log that i get is:

```
> generating menu
> adding a class to: 
> []
```

so it appears that the element i'm looking for hasn't been added to the DOM yet.
I think there should be some solution using `live()`, but when I try `live('load',...)` it never gets called...

Comment: creating the menubar with javascript based on permissions doesn't seem very secure to me

Comment: @ianbarker- do you have any reasons for thinking that?

Comment: because it makes it easy for somebody to see the urls of things that they are not allowed to access, by looking in the js source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for the problem was to generate JavaScript which reads:

```
 var BASE_URL = 'http://server/app/...'
```

All my URLs are either absolute or relative to `BASE_URL`. That way, I can simply look for all links which go to the current page and add the class "current" to them (take the URL for the current page, cut `BASE_URL` away and use the resulting string to query for `a[href="..."]`

For your solution, I think the problem is that you run `SetCurrentPage()` after the page has loaded when you should call it after the "load menu" AJAX call has come back.

Move the calls to the two methods to the end of the success callback in `InitializeCurrentUser()` and it should work.

Comment: how silly of me. I moved `SetCurrentPage()` to the end of the success callback. of course.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot `var` before `currentPage`

```
$(function() {

    //set this page as the current page; 
   var  currentPage = Enum.Page.Reports;
});
```

make sure that your function SetCurrentPage is being called after dom.ready event

Comment: i don't think that's the problem; `currentPage` is defined in menubar.js, and is only referenced in other scripts.

Comment: and is that closed in function for example?

Comment: of course not, otherwise it wouldn't be recognized by other scripts. the problem isn't the value of this variable- the value is set fine. the problem is that the selector returns empty