# Jquery change css class when achor clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add a class to a list item when the item is clicked. I did some research and still was unable to add the class properly. thanks!

edit:I am using a masterpage in asp.net

```
<ul id="menu">
      <!-- put class="selected" in the li tag for the selected page - to highlight which page you're on -->
      <li><a id="default" href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
       <li><a id="projects" href="Projects.aspx">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a id="blogs" href="Blogs.aspx">Blogs</a></li>
      <li><a id="photos" href="Photos.aspx">Photos</a></li>
       <li><a id="resume" href="Resume.aspx">Resume</a></li>
      <li><a id="contacts" href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('ul.menu li a').click(function () {
           $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
       });
   });
```

```
ul#menu li a:hover, ul#menu li.selected a, ul#menu li.selected a:hover
```

{ color: #FFF;
  background: #1C2C3E url(menu_select.png) repeat-x;}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your selector is incorrect. `ul.menu` means a ul with class `menu`.
when looking for an id, simply use `$("#menu")`

also, you may want to take a look at the answers given by @DefyGravity and @Joseph Silber-
they suggest that if you don't prevent the default click event, the user's browser would simply follow the link, and the user would never actually see the added class, since they'll be navigated to a different page.

Comment: sJhonny was first, +1, highly recommend the prevent default.  Optionally, remove the 'selected' class from the sibling <li>'s.

Comment: How would can you change the page then?

Comment: you should add your 'selected' class on load (and not when clicking a link), based on the current page that you're on. see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690930/how-to-manipulate-on-document-ready-elements-which-were-created-on-document-rea

Answer (score 1):

Change your jQuery to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul#menu li a').click(function (e) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

You had the `ul.menu` which is referring to a class of menu, where as you have an ID of menu on the tag

Answer (score 1):

You have to return false, otherwise the browser just follows the link:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $('ul#menu li a').click(function () {
           $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
           return false;
       });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in your selector, ul.menu  looks for a unordered list with a 'class' of menu.  your html states it the un-ordered list has an ID of menu.  You may also want to 'event.preventDefault()':

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $('#menu li a').click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
                   $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
// also think about removing the class 'selected' from all the other links.
  $(this).parent().siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
               });
           });
        </script>
```

Comment: How to change page if you prevent the default?