# jQuery current page highlight

Tags: jquery, highlight

How can I use jQuery to highlight the current page? In other words, add a "current" class to the a element of the current page.

Here's my code:

```
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../articles/">Articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="../photos/">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="../info/">Earthquake Info</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I've researched several different approaches, but most of them rely on linking to pages (i.e. `articles.html`) instead of directories (i.e. `../articles/`).

I've seen the body/ID class method and would prefer an automatic jQuery solution.

[Here's my site](http://bit.ly/phuNaH).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it on my personal site. (Link [Here](http://joshua-smith.net/))

```
<ul id="navLinks">
    <li><a id="homeLink" href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="blogLink" href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a id="photosLink" href="/photo-gallery/">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a id="portfolioLink" href="/portfolio/">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a id="contactLink" href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>



var section = window.location.pathname;

if (section == '/') { $('#homeLink').attr('class', 'selected'); }
if (section.substring(0, 5) == "/blog") { $('#blogLink').attr('class', 'selected'); }
if (section.substring(0, 9) == "/articles") { $('#blogLink').attr('class', 'selected'); }
if (section.substring(0, 8) == "/contact") { $('#contactLink').attr('class', 'selected'); }
if (section.substring(0, 14) == "/photo-gallery") { $('#photosLink').attr('class', 'selected'); }
if (section.substring(0, 10) == "/portfolio") { $('#portfolioLink').attr('class', 'selected'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `document.location.href` and spliting the string.

Run a loop through your elements compare them to splited string and add class to right one.

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690930/how-to-manipulate-on-document-ready-elements-which-were-created-on-document-rea/6691188#6691188) should sort you out.
you might need to tweak it slightly to work with folders..

Comment: This looks like it could work, but is there a way to implement this without the extra code for the user's permissions? Do you have a sample script or page I could look at?

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't find a jQuery solution, I did find a nice [Javascript alternative](http://www.richnetapps.com/automatically_highlight_current_page_in/).